# Python: Conditionally throwing an exception based on module-level variable

Tags: python

I have a quite sizeable chunk of logic (say 100k lines of code) that are intended to validate a Python object which makes refactoring when `Exceptions` are thrown hard if not done incrementally.

The logic above will throw an `Exception` when an invalid object is passed in.

The logic might look something like this:

```
def someCheck(self):
  if not_valid1(self.some_object):
    raise CustomException(...)

  if not_valid2(self.some_object):
    raise CustomException(...)

   ...
```

I would like to be able to annotate or wrap the exceptions so that some `not_valid*()` checks are silently ignored when a module-level variable is set to `True`.

For example, if `IGNORE_CHECKS = True`, then we should not raise the `CustomException` when `not_valid1(...)` is `True` above, but the `is_valid2(...)` check should still run.

Is there an easy way to do this?

For example, something like:

```
def someCheck(self):
  if not_valid1(self.some_object):
    raise CustomExceptionThatIsSlientlyIgnoredWhenIgnoreChecksIsTrue(...)

  if not_valid2(self.some_object):
    raise CustomException(...)

   ...
```

or

```
def someCheck(self):
  if not_valid1(self.some_object):
    raise CustomExceptionThatIsSlientlyIgnoredWhenIgnoreChecksIsTrue(CustomException(...))

  if not_valid2(self.some_object):
    raise CustomException(...)

   ...
```

I can do something like:

```
def someCheck(self):
  if not IGNORE_CHECKS and not_valid1(self.some_object):
    raise CustomException(...)

  if not_valid2(self.some_object):
    raise CustomException(...)

   ...
```

but it gets unweidly if `IGNORE_CHECKS` needs to be sprinkled in hundreds/thousands of times across the often complex code.

Comment: Adding `not IGNORE_CHECKS and` to the condition seems a lot cleaner than the other options you propose.

Comment: Do you have control over `not_valid1`, or for some weird reason only over `CustomExceptionThatIsSlientlyIgnoredWhenIgnoreChecksIsTrue`? If you have control over neither, there is no way to resume execution after the exception has been raised as if it had never been raised.

Comment: If I understand properly, you want to ignore all `is_valid1` failures across the file, and do it only for some check functions. Why not just wrap `if IGNORE_CHECKS: is_valid1 = lambda _: True` (ofc with def, it's just less readable in comments)? Or even wrap it into function calling old `is_valid1` and discarding its return value, returning True, so that you still know that check doesn't cause large bomb explosion.

Comment: I am confused... where are you using `is_valid`?  all i see are `not_valid` function calls

Comment: I assume this is a temporary thing for the refactoring? Party's over as soon as you hit the `raise` statement, so can't fix it with a different exception. If the functions don't do anything other than validate, you could temporarily replace them - `def boring(*args, **kwargs): pass` and then `not_check1 = boring` before the function call when you don't want it. maybe even the python mock module to inject the info.